# on refresh route is directing to default route using angular2 router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

Iam using angular2 router to configure routing for my application Here is my code snippet.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UpdateprofileComponent } from './updateprofile/updateprofile.component';
import { ChangepasswordComponent } from './changepassword/changepassword.component';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  { path: 'updateprofile', component: UpdateprofileComponent },
  { path: 'changepassword', component: ChangepasswordComponent },
  // Not found
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    UpdateprofileComponent,
    ChangepasswordComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [CookieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

header.component.html

```
<header>
   <select [(ngModel)]="userOperationType" (ngModelChange)="fnSetOperationType(userOperationType)" class="col-md-12 select-style">
                        <option value="dashboard">Account Administration</option>
                        <option value="changepassword" selected>Change Password</option>
                        <option value="updateprofile">Your Profile</option>
                    </select>
</header>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetailsService } from '../services/user-details.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  providers: [UserDetailsService]
})
export class NvidiaHeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }


  fnSetOperationType(routeName) {
    this.route.navigate([routeName]);

  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular2Routing</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>loading...
  </app-root>
  <script type = "text/javascript" >
history.pushState(null, null, '/#/dashboard');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
history.pushState(null, null, '/#/dashboard');
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my routing in app.module.ts. After navigating to changepassword route my url is http://localhost:4200/#/changepassword. When iam refreshing my page or opening this url in new tab my url is redirecting to http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard (default route).

I need to get the same route after refreshing my page or if i copy paste the route in another tab i need to get corresponding route.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing use as default from your dashboard path.Instead of going to your wildcard path router is picking up the use as default config

Comment: Are you using Apache as web server?

Comment: @HassanFalahi Iam not using Apache iam just doing it using angular-cli . ng serve does my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a small mistake in index.html. I have removed the following script. I used it to work on clearing browser history.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
history.pushState(null, null, '/#/dashboard');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
history.pushState(null, null, '/#/dashboard');
});
</script>
```

It worked like charm !!! Thanks for the help.:)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `useAsDefault: true`, try to redirect the default route to your dashboard :

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    //useAsDefault: true //remove this
}
```

Comment: I removed useAsDefault but still no use @mickdev

Comment: did you 'manually' redirect in `ChangepasswordComponent` ? Can you edit your question and provide its code ?

Comment: Also try to change router order, put changepass... before dashboard and see if that resolve your issue.

Comment: sure i will update my question and make the changes suggented bu you

Comment: @mikedev i have updated my question please have look on it. After changing the routing order also didn't helped me.

Comment: Instead of you `ChangepasswordComponent` you provided `NvidiaHeaderComponent`. I want to see if you redirect somehow in `ChangepasswordComponent`. Can you provide the correct component ?

Comment: Please find the updated question with `ChangepasswordComponent`

Comment: ok, so `ChangepasswordComponent` has `NvidiaHeaderComponent` as child and the function `fnSetOperationType()` redirect to correct route ... I can't see nothing suspicious here. Can you provide a Plunker reproducing your issue